# Expected Value of Maximum likelihood mean for Gaussian Distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, mean

In the process of finding unknown parameters $\mu$(mean) and $\sigma^2$(variance) for the **maximum likelihood** function for Gaussian distribution, we arrive at the following equation.

> $\begin{align*}  &\ln\left [ \bf p\left ( x | \mu,\sigma ^2 \right )
>  \right ] = -\frac{N}{2}\ln (2 \pi) - \frac{N}{2}\ln(\sigma ^2) -
>  \frac{1}{2\cdot \sigma ^2} \left \{ \sum_{n=1}^{N}(x_n - \mu)^2 \right
>  \} \\ &\text{where } { \bf x } = \left ( x_1,x_2,x_3 \dots x_N \right
>  )^T \text{ is a data set of observation. } \\ \end{align*}$

Now by differentiating and maximizing with respect to $\mu$ we get

> \begin{align*}  {\bf \mu_{ml}} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}x_n \\
>  \end{align*}

Now how to evaluate **Expected value** of $\bf\mu_{ml}$ ? I am not able to apply summation rule for expected value. I tried
$E\left ( \bf \mu_{ml} \right ) = \sum_{??}^{??} \left ( \mu_{ml} \right ) \cdot \left [ p \left ( {\bf x} | \mu_{ml},\sigma^2 \right ) \right ]$.

Comment: The equivalent to summation for continuous distributions is integration.

Comment: Thanks ! But what is the domain of integration?

Comment: What is the domain of the random variable?

Comment: OK. That means it is same as the domain of the random variable $x$. It is not explicitly mentioned in the text about the domain of $x$. However the answer to $E(\mu_{ml})$ is given as $\mu$. Could you please help a little bit how they derived?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $
> \begin{align*}  &\text{Using} \; \\ &E\left [ X+Y \right ] =E[X]+E[Y]
>  \\ &E[\mu_{\text{ml}}] =  \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n = 1}^{N}E(x_n) 
>  \end{align*} $

Since each $x_i$ is a Random Variable picked uniformly from a Gaussian distribution, the expected value of each is just the mean of the distribution. That is $E[x_i] = \mu$ for each $x_i$.

Thus $E[\mu_{ml}] =  \frac{1}{N}\cdot N \cdot \mu = \mu$